# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

Getting following error:

> 06-20 17:46:59.993 9707-9781/com.example.admin.demoasync W/System.err: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG @2:44 in java.io.InputStreamReader@1747caf6)

while executing following code(used ksoap2 library):

```
public class Webservice
{
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://micraft.org/webservice/";
    private static String URL = "http://billbox.micraft.org/webservice.asmx";
    private static String SOAP_ACTION= "http://micraft.org/webservices/GetUsers";

    public static boolean invokeWS(String userEmail,String userPass,String webMethName)
    {
        boolean loginStatus = false;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
        PropertyInfo unamePI = new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo passPI = new PropertyInfo();
        unamePI.setName("UserID");
        unamePI.setValue(userEmail);
        unamePI.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(unamePI);
        passPI.setName("Password");
        passPI.setValue(userPass);
        passPI.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(passPI);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        Log.e("Envelope", String.valueOf(request));
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + webMethName, envelope);
            Log.e("Enevelope2",String.valueOf(envelope));
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            loginStatus = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            MainActivity.errored = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return loginStatus;
    }
}
```

Tried all stack-overflow suggestions, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Following is request sent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header /><v:Body><GetUsers xmlns="http://micraft.org/webservices/"><UserID>******</UserID><Password>***</Password></GetUsers></v:Body></v:Envelope>
```

And, following is response received :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```